# Perl hashes sorting

Tags: perl, hash

Hi i need to sort the hashes keys.

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use Data::Dumper;

my %FileRead_hash=('wan1','0','wan2', '0','wan3','1','wan4','1','wan5','0');
#print keys %FileRead_hash;
while (my ($key, $value) = each %FileRead_hash)
{
    if  ($value eq 0)
    {
        say  $key. "success";
    }
    else 
    {
        say $key. "failure";
    }
}
```

Output of this would be

```
wan4 failure
wan1 success
wan3 failure
wan5 success
wan2 success
```

I am trying to get the output in the order key (like ascending order).

Something like this

```
wan1 failure
wan2 success
wan3 failure
wan4 success
wan5 success
```

Someone please advice me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Good style would be to associate keys and values via `=>` in your hash. E.g.: `my %FileRead_hash=('wan1'=>'0','wan2'=> '0','wan3'=>'1','wan4'=>'1','wan5'=>'0');`

Comment: You might wish to consider whether you really want string equality comparison `eq` for the number, or if what you really want is numeric equality comparison `==`. For example `"0.0" eq 0` is false, whereas `"0.0" == 0` is true.

Comment: `if ( $value eq 0 )` should be `if ( $value == 0 )`. `eq` is for comparing strings. `==` is for comparing numbers. Or better yet, you should simply check for truth: `if ( !$value )`. Personally, I'd use `if ( $value )` and flip the then/else blocks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should sort the keys separately and then use use them to access the corresponding values

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my %file_read = (
    wan1 => 0,
    wan2 => 0,
    wan3 => 1,
    wan4 => 1,
    wan5 => 0,
);

for my $key ( sort keys %file_read ) {

    my $value = $file_read{$key};

    if ( $value eq 0 ) {
        say "$key success";
    }
    else {
        say "$key failure";
    }
}
```

#### output

```
wan1 success
wan2 success
wan3 failure
wan4 failure
wan5 success
```

Comment: @ashvak, If it goes beyond 9, you'll need something like Sort::Key::Natural.